# A detail of the definition of limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

From Rudin's book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* Definition 4.1

> For every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that
>   $$d_Y(f(x),q)<\epsilon$$
>   for all points $x\in E$ for which
>   $$0<d_X(x,p)<\delta$$

I think a limit $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=q$ is something that we don't care about the point $p$ and $q$, we just focus on the tendency.

It makes sense in $0<d_X(x,p)<\delta$, we don't care the point $p$.

However, why it is $d_Y(f(x),q)<\epsilon$, it just take the $q$ into account. I think it should be  $0<d_Y(f(x),q)<\epsilon$, so that the $q$ isn't take into account.

I know that $d_Y(f(x),q)<\epsilon$ is a bigger set of $0<d_Y(f(x),q)<\epsilon$, which means if we found some $0<d_X(x,p)<\delta$ satisfy $0<d_Y(f(x),q)<\epsilon$, it do satisfy the $d_Y(f(x),q)<\epsilon$, so the  $d_Y(f(x),q)<\epsilon$ is more harder.

but why, why we choose  $d_Y(f(x),q)<\epsilon$ rather than $0<d_Y(f(x),q)<\epsilon$.

Comment: It could be that $f(x)=f(p)$ even if $x\ne p$ (for example, a constant function)

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think a limit $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=q$ is something that we don't care about the point $p$ and $q$, we just focus on the tendency.

That is true: we don't care about the exact value **at** point $p$ (hence the $0 < d_X(x,p) < \varepsilon$), and we don't care whether $f(x)$ becomes *exactly* $q$.

However, in the former case, just asking for $0 < d_X(x,p) < \delta$ is a *relaxation*: it literally means "there is no condition you have to verify at the specific point $p$ itself." If we added $0 < d_Y(f(x),q) < \varepsilon$ to the latter, however, it would be a *strenghtening*: it would *add* a condition (namely, "on top of the rest, you *cannot* take the value $q$).

That's the idea: we don't care about the value at $p$, so we don't have any constraint at $p$. And indeed we don't care whether the value becomes exactly $q$, so we don't add that constraint — but, more importantly, we also don't care that the value does **not** become $q$, so we don't add that extra constraint either saying "you **cannot** take the value $q$." That wouldn't capture what we want.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f(x)=0$, a constant function on $\mathbb R$.

Wouldn't we want $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0,$ even though $d_Y(f(x),f(0))=0$ for all $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence

"I think a limit $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=q$ is something that we don't care about the point $p$ and $q$, we just focus on the tendency"

misses the point: This sentence should read

"When considering the limit $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)$ we don't care about the possible value of $f$ at the point $p$, we just focus on the tendency."

It could very well happen that $f$ assumes the value $q$ in some points  $x$ near $p$. The essential demand is that $f(x)$ is "near" $q$ while $x$ is sufficiently near $p$, but $\ne p$. When the point $f(x)$ is actually $=q$ then it surely is "near" $q$. Consider this example:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{\sin x\over x}=0\ .\tag{1}$$
Here $f(x)=0$ in many points $x$ "near" $\infty$. Your condition $0<d\bigl(f(x),q\bigr)<\epsilon$ would make $(1)$ false.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, for instance,$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }x\in\mathbb Q\\0&\text{ if }x\notin\mathbb Q.\end{cases}$$I suppose that you agree that, when $x$ is close to $0$; then $f(x)$ is close to $0$ too. In other words, $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$. But if, in the definition of limit, we had $0<\bigl(d(f(x),q\bigr)<\varepsilon$, then the limit $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ would not exist.